# App Name shows ellipsis at the end of name when downloaded from App Store

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ios8, xcode6

My App shows ellipsis `...` at the end of name when I download it from Apple App Store, But shows Full name when Building from Xcode.

It is only 11 characters long, with Two capital letters.

XCode - 6.4(6E35b)
iOS - 8.4

AppName = GoldTracker

Any Idea ?

Comment: this is happening for iPhone 6 Plus only... right?

Comment: Well, it is happening in all devices but not on the simulators :(

Comment: Use a shorter name? What kind of a solution are you expecting?

Comment: I want to show full name as there are many apps using larger name then mine :(

Comment: Let me download your app and check...

Comment: Why you want iOS 8.3? Keep the app with 7.0 compatible...

Comment: Sure, Its GoldTracker Me on App Store

Comment: Try with small letters and see how it goes? I think its just bcz of CAPS...

Comment: app crashing... why?

Comment: `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 44 beyond bounds [0 .. 43]'`

Comment: Yes there are known crashes. I am working on them now.

Comment: Let me make it compatible with 7.0 and try your suggestion

Comment: Well, I think you cannot create an Apple watch Extension with below 8.0 iOS version.

Comment: There is an App named Sopt Tracker it is showing full name .. Why ?

Comment: It worked with GoldTrack But didn't with GoldTracker

Comment: App names are not bound to the amount of character but the size of the characters together. An 'M' is bigger than 'I' for example

Comment: You are right Jasper .. I know that, But Spot Tracker isn't longer then GoldTracker ?

Comment: isn't there any solution ?